# MvcMailer: The context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package, mvcmailer

i cant seem to figured out why i cant install nuget pakcage

ive tried running this in visual studio 2010 package manager

```
Install-Package MvcMailer
```

but i get an error shown below

```
PM> install-package MvcMailer
Install-Package : The context is already tracking a different entity with the same        resource Uri.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  MvcMailer
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :    NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

any ideas how to resolve this issue? tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/51efcc96-e5ef-4fd1-918f-35bf05c5a7d3/exception-the-context-is-already-tracking-a-different-entity-with-the-same-resource-uri?forum=windowsazuredata):

> this error will occur if deserialized type dont really match the data Type of the entity being tracked. a fix for this is via using no tracking option.
>
> more information can be found here
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.mergeoption.aspx

also, it is advisable to use a new, different Data Service Context for every logical operation like insert and queries context.